# When is errno set

Tags: c, file, io, errno

In C I know that you can see the errors using `errno` in `errno.h` and I have the following code

```c
int FS_copyFile(const char* PathFrom , const char* PathTo) {
    FILE* Source;
    FILE* Target;

    struct stat st;
    stat(PathFrom, &st);

    char SourceFileData[st.st_size];

    Source = fopen(PathFrom , "r");

    if(Source == NULL) {
        return errno;
    }

    Target = fopen(PathTo , "w");

    if(Target == NULL) {
        return errno;
    }

    fgets(SourceFileData, st.st_size + 1, Source); 

    fputs(SourceFileData , Target);

    fclose(Source);
    fclose(Target);
}
```

But I am unsure when `errno` is set. Let us say that the file `foo.txt` that cannot be written to. Will `errno` be set when opening the file for writing or attempting to write to it?

I have tried looking online but i can't find anything that actually says when `errno` is set. In which parts of my code will errno be set if an error happens?

Comment: `errno` is set when a certain function is documented to set it. As in in [man fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen): *"Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a FILE pointer. Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error."*

Comment: @EugeneSh. So it is possible for an error to occur while writing to a file but not opening it for writing?

Comment: I have no idea how my comment lead you to this conclusion. But sure, error can happen on any IO operation, why not...

Comment: as a user of `fopen`, you don't care about the inner workings or implementation details, it's a black box to you. You call it to open a file, if that fails, then you detect the error via return value and know that `fopen` has set errno with the appropriate error code to offer further information on what went wrong. _When_ is that actually set inside `fopen` ... who cares? All you need to know is it will be set upon return. If you really _do_ care for your own edification, I'm sure you can find `fopen` source code readily available online. But simply as an `fopen` user, you don't care.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was wondering if the kernel checks that the file can be read from and not just the permissions it has but I guess a file read error is possible. Ty!

Comment: [Here's Apple's](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1272.200.26/stdio/FreeBSD/fopen.c.auto.html) implementation of `fopen`, at least at one point in time. `errno` is actually sent once in here, but you'll need to dive deeper into `_open` and probably some of the other functions it calls to find all places where `errno` is set.

Comment: So looks like your question is basically "Will `fopen` fail if opened for writing but does not have write permission?".  If so, then why not ask it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for functions in the standard C library is that functions whose documentation says they set `errno` set `errno` as documented and that functions whose documentation is silent about `errno` might set `errno` to non-zero, even if no error occurs. (This is because the function might call other routines to do some work, and those routines might report an error, after which the parent routine might resolve the error in some way, so it can successfully complete the task its caller requested, but it may leave `errno` set.) C 2018 7.5 2 says:

> … The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of `errno` in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function. The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this document.

Functions other than those in the standard C library may behave differently. For example, on macOS, the `fts_read` function will clear `errno` to indicate a tree traversal is complete:

> … If all the members of the hierarchy have been returned, **fts_read()** returns NULL and sets the external variable *errno* to 0…

> Will `errno` be set when opening the file for writing or attempting to write to it?

The C standard’s specifications for `fopen` and `fwrite` do not mention `errno`, so they may or may not set `errno`. Specific implementations of these routines might document that they set `errno`. For example, the macOS documentation for `fopen` indicates it may fail and set `errno` due to failures in `malloc` or `open` (or equivalent).

Note that `fwrite` is typically buffered, so any failures to write to a file might not occur immediately. If not reported by `fwrite`, they should be reported by `fflush` or `fclose`.